# How do I use passed in generic Lists of objects and return a generic object with my Java method?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make my application more efficient by using Java generics, but I don't have a lot of generics experience. I am trying to do this:

**My Two Model Objects:**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    // ...

    // Getters and Setters Here
}

public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private int year;
    // ...

    // Getters and Setters Here
}
```

**My Result Objects:**

```
private class PersonResult {
    private boolean success;
    private String notes;
    private int score;

    // Getters and Setters Here
}

private class CarResult {
    private boolean success;
    private String notes;
    private int score;
    private double price;

    // Getters and Setters Here
}
```

**My Main Class:**

```
public class MyClass{

    public mainMethod(){

        List<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<>();

        listOfPersons.add(// a Person object);
        // ...

        listOfCars.add(// a Car object);
        // ...

        PersonResult = resultMethod(listOfPersons);
        CarResult = resultMethod(listOfCars);
    }

    private <E,T> E resultMethod(List<T> listOfData)
    {
        Engine engine = EngineFactory.getEngine();

        // if(listOfData.contains(Person.class))
        if (listOfData instanceof List<Person>)
        {
            PersonResult personResult = new PersonResult();
            perosnResult = engine.getPersonResult(listOfData);
            return personResult;
        }
        // else if(listOfData.contains(Car.class))
        else if (listOfData instanceof List<Car>)
        {
            CarResult carResult = new CarResult();
            carResult engine.getCarResult(listOfData);
            return carResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

However my IDE is complaining about:

1 `Illegal generic type for instanceof`

2 (for the return value) `Incompatible types: Required: E - Found PersonResult`

As you can see, I also tried `listOfData.contains(Person.class)`, that took care of error #1, but not the return error.

Comment: I guess the simpler way is to create two methods resultMethodPerson, resultMethodCar, that receive the corresponding list

Comment: The whole point of using generics, well one point at least :), is to not be needing to use `instanceof` in the code. And your resultMethod is hard to understand what your intention with it is. Hint, make a Result class that is generic instead and use it with Person and Car.

Comment: If you find yourself using instanceof in your "generic" method, chances are that that method is not and should not be generic

Comment: @RobOhRob What about my use of `listOfData.contains(Person.class)`?

Comment: @Brian That won't work, because `listOfData` doesn't contain `Class<Person>` objects. I'm afraid that you are trying to define a relationship between classes that is in fact not really there...

Comment: No.... If the parameter is a `List<T> listOfData`, one is to assume that what T is doesn't matter at all... The only thing that matters is that it's a list...in other words you are only going to do things that apply to every list..like print...or clear

Comment: there is no generic handling for getting result of Person and Car as you are calling two different methods, which suggests that you should not be using generics

Comment: Look into `engine.getPersonResult(listOfData);` and `engine.getCarResult(listOfData);`... how similar are those methods? That might be a spot to use generics

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test for generic parameters by `instanceof`. `instanceof` will be evaluated at runtime. But the compiler removes the generic types. They are not present at runtime. For example `List<Integer>` will be the same as `List` at runtime.

You can use a simple implementation without generics here:

```
private PersonResult resultMethodPerson(List<Person> listOfData) {
  return EngineFactory.getEngine().getPersonResult(listOfData);
}

private CarResult resultMethodCar(List<Car> listOfData) {
  return EngineFactory.getEngine().getCarResult(listOfData);
}
```